# Which location on disk can NT AUTHORITY\Network Service always write to when running asp.net app pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net, network-service

I am running a c# website as the Network Service principal. Even with 'Load User Profile' set to **true** on the application pool, i can't seem to resolve special folders (e.g. `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`), as the call to `Environment.GetFolderPath()` returns C:\ always, and NetworkService does not have permissions to write to it.

I know that if i run `aspnet_regiis -ga "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"` i would get permissions to ASP.NET temporary folders. However, i need some permanent location (e.g. not really a temp folder) to write to. I do not particularly care which location it is, so long as it is the same on each system running Windows 2008/R2/2012/R2.

Comment: Why does it have to be a fixed file system location? (I.e. why isn't e.g. the `App_Data` folder within the website a suitable location?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, i want to log information from several websites and a windows service to a single location. This file is only updated when all other means to log that information have failed, and thus will not contend for resources much (and i have a workaround by creating timestamped copies when the original is unavailable). But the administrators do not want to look around for all files with information and then marry up the timestamps to work out event flow.